# Why can't I segue to a view controller in my XIB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7.1

In my code below, I am getting an error saying "Property "navigationController" not found on object of type 'iPhoneFirstPageView *'. This worked before in a different project, but it won't work in this XIB. Any ideas?

```
-(IBAction)Twitter {
    TwitterViewController *twitter = [[TwitterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    //[self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:NULL];
    //[self presentModalViewController:twitter animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:TwitterViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that on this line:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:TwitterViewController animated:YES];
```

You are trying to push the CLASS `TwitterViewController`rather than your object `twitter`

Your second problem is that `iPhoneFirstPageView` is a subclass of `UIView` and not of `UIViewController`. The cleanest way for someone new to fix this would be in Xcode to create a new file called `iPhoneFirstPageViewController` that is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

The solution setup your initial view controllers as the follow:

```
iPhoneFirstPageViewController *firstViewController = [[iPhoneFirstPageViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

////Skip to the method you are trying to write. This will be in iPhoneFirstPageViewController.m

-(IBAction)Twitter
 {
    TwitterViewController *twitter = [[TwitterViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:twitter animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: iPhoneFirstPage is a UIView XIB. All I want to do is segue from the UIView that will be in a scroll view, to another ViewController, am I even approaching this the right way?

Comment: `UIView` does not have a pointer to a `UINavigationController`. 

Usually the way you would have the app works is that you have a `UINavigationController` that has a `rootViewController`. This would be `iPhoneFirstPageViewCONTROLLER`. Then inside of `iPhoneFirstPageViewCONTROLLER` you would tell it's `UINavigationController` to push onto the stack of controller the second controller, which is your `TwitterViewController`. 

I'll update my answer as I'm running out of room in this comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the only problem is, when I try to load a UIViewController in my scroll view as a page, the app crashes.

Comment: Yes, you cannot put a `UIViewController` inside of a `UIScrollView`, only subclasses of `UIView`.

What contains your `UIScrollView`? It has to be some sort of `UIViewController`. You need to call the `-(IBAction)Twitter` method from inside of that `UIViewController`

Comment: In the app, I have a UIViewController that contains a scrollview. The scrollview takes XIB files to create pages in the scroll view. All I'm trying accomplish is link a button in one of the UIView XIBs, to a separate view controller. How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: So inside of your `UIViewController`, you must at some point call (I'm writing pseudocode, so this isn't exactly the method) :

`[self.scrollView addSubview:myIPhoneView];`

Correct?

If so, then I would add a `@property` pointer to either the `UIViewController` (that has the `UIScrollView`) or the `UINavigationController` of the `UIViewController` to the `iPhoneFirstPageView` class. That way you can either call `self.viewController.navigationController push`... or `self.navigationController push...`

Comment: I fixed the error, and the app runs, but the button still will not segue. I assume there is something stupid I am doing. You can find my project here: https://github.com/rileylloyd24/Cazenovia